# Vim colors not working properly in terminal

Tags: vim, colors, gnome-terminal

I'm using gnome terminal, and vim with solarized color theme. When I open vim in the terminal, it's illegible.

[image: vim opened in the terminal]

But when I open a file in gvim, the color scheme works perfectly.

[image: gvim]

Gnome terminal's color scheme is also solarized. One thing to note is that, if I set an illegal value for background, I get the expected background color (but also an error).

Comment: Could you add your .vimrc and .gvimrc?

Comment: .vimrc is [here](https://gist.github.com/1508286) there's no .gvimrc. I already checked the question on the 1st comment. My &term and $TERM are both the same (xterm-256color).

Comment: Found a temporary fix, adding [this](https://gist.github.com/1508312) before colorscheme solarized. Changes the colors to the solarized theme. But, the line numbers column keeps having a brownish-grey color.

Comment: Might I suggest installing `terminator` (a great, solid terminal emulator), and then going `Preferences>Profiles>Colors>Palette` and selecting `Solarized`. Additionally, (as I have it) you can go to `Keybindings` and map `super+p` or whatever you want to change to the next profile (which would contain a different profile). I have two profiles - solarized and another more colorful one that I do everything but `vim` in. Whenever I go into `vim` now, I simply hit `super+p` and then my palette matches that which the creator of solarized had intended. Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To complete Akira's advice, vim in term mode uses the terminal color palette. From the vim solarized colorscheme repo :

> If you are going to use Solarized in Terminal mode (i.e. not in a GUI
>   version like gvim or macvim), please please please consider setting
>   your terminal emulator's colorscheme to used the Solarized palette.
>   I've included palettes for some popular terminal emulator as well as
>   Xdefaults in the official Solarized download available from [Solarized
>   homepage](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized).

For gnome-term, there are instructions to [set up the color palette](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/solarized-must-have-color-paletter-for.html).

Comment: Had the same problem today, when trying to setup a new system, and after setting the colors in ~/.Xresources and merging using xrdb. The color problems with vim in terminal session is gone.

Comment: Useful gconf code block to set up gnome-terminal: http://www.xorcode.com/2011/04/11/solarized-vim-eclipse-ubuntu/

Comment: See akira’s answer below for the magic incantation: `export TERM=xterm-256color vim` (and then put the `export` command in your shell startup file, like bashrc).

Answer (score 19):

`vim` use the power of your "terminal" to draw the characters onto the screen. thus, how the drawn chars look depend largely on what the "terminal" is capable of. the "terminal" uses an enviroment variable to tell the apps running inside it about its capabilities: `TERM`.

if you want to use `vim` to use 256 colors you need 2 things:

- a terminal capable of rendering at least 256 colors
- the right `TERM` variable (`xterm-256color`)

so, try this:

```
$ export TERM=xterm-256color
$ vim
```

also read up more upon the topic on http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim

Comment: By running this commmand, I was able to use the `vim` extension `Powerline` in my `gnome-terminal`. Thank you!

Comment: even with 256 colors, a lot of colorschemes look off.. but I guess that is explained by the color palette

Answer (score 1):

Referencing:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66579/how-do-i-get-the-solarized-colour-scheme-working-with-gnome-terminal-tmux-and-v/141624#141624

I give the same response here:
According to Koraktors comment, executeing `:set t_Co=16` fixed the mixed colors issue immediately for me, so I added it to `~/.vimrc` to sustain the correction.

You really don't want to enable the 256 colors, it actually decrease the how close you can get to the solarized pallette. From the [devs website](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized):

> IMPORTANT NOTE FOR TERMINAL USERS:
>
> If you are going to use Solarized in Terminal mode (i.e. not in a GUI
>   version like gvim or macvim), please please please consider setting
>   your terminal emulator’s colorscheme to used the Solarized palette.
>   I’ve included palettes for some popular terminal emulator as well as
>   Xdefaults in the official Solarized download available from Solarized
>   homepage. If you use Solarized without these colors, Solarized will
>   need to be told to degrade its colorscheme to a set compatible with
>   the limited 256 terminal palette (whereas by using the terminal’s 16
>   ansi color values, you can set the correct, specific values for the
>   Solarized palette).

Answer (score -3):

Workaround for the grey number background color:

Open `solarized.vim`, search for `LineNr`, remove the line.